# Uncommon Terms Meaning Deadeye in the Sense of Unerring Marksman

Tags: word-request

How are you doing?

I came across this very interesting Question on the English Language & Usage Site ([Origin of the term "deadeye" meaning "expert marksman"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323539/origin-of-the-term-deadeye-meaning-expert-marksman)) just a few days ago. I decided not to ask about this on that Site, as I am not a serious English language enthusiast, but just rather came up with this question based on what I read there.

I wondered which would be some rather uncommon terms meaning ***Deadeye***, in the sense of *unerring marksman*, as stated in the [Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deadeye).

Some searching for synonyms lead me to Sites such as *Thesaurus.com*, and stated some were *Sharpshooter*, *Marksman*, and *Sniper*. These, as far as my knowledge goes, are rather common terms. Further searching, this time focusing on similar terms, such as *Archer* or *Hunter*, lead me to unsatisfactory results.

Two Posters on the Question mentioned, listed some rather interesting (and uncommon, as far as my knowledge goes) terms related to *Deadeye*: ***Dead Shot***, ***Sure-Eyed***, ***Keen-Eyed***, and ***True-Eyed***.

Even further research lead me to two terms, existing on the Video game *Fortnite*, as Cosmetic Upgrades for two Characters: ***Sureshot*** and ***Bullseye***. The former sounds like an existing term, but could be made up. I know *Bullseye* is *the dead center of a target*, so I doubt it could mean *an unerring marksman*.

Which could be some uncommon and interesting terms meaning *Deadeye*? I am especially interested on those which end on ***-shot*** and ***-eye(d)***.

Comment: ***Keen-eyed*** is well-established, but it means *having good eyesight*, not  "marksmanship" (skill / accuracy in *shooting*). The other two *(**sure-eyed, true-eyed**)* have no currency in English - but if they *did*, I'm sure they'd mean the same as ***keen-eyed***.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about the purpose of this question. You've already looked in dictionaries and thesauruses and found several synonyms there. Do you believe that those lists are not complete? Are you looking for a specific term? Are you more interested in the relative frequency of the terms you've already found? Or is there some other reason?

Comment: **You are doing it wrong**.  You shouldn't be looking for the uncommon terms, because those are by definition the ones that native speakers don't use much. . .  You should be looking for the **common** way of expressing an idea.... If you want a rare expression, you can make one up - similies are a good way "He shot as straight a woodcock's bill"  There you go, that's rare! in fact I think I'm the first person ever to use that simile.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is, from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crack%20shot)

> **crack shot**
>
> a person who is very good at shooting a gun
> *I hear she's become a crack shot*

Interestingly (perhaps), a similar term [means](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/straight%20shooter) something rather different

> **straight shooter**
>
> a thoroughly upright straightforward person
> *He's a straight shooter who says what he thinks.*